# Upgrading Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have recently bought a new laptop which has Windows 10 Home preinstalled.

I also have a retail Windows 10 Pro MSDN disk. Can I upgrade the Windows 10 home to Windows 10 pro directly, Without formatting the disk?

Comment: This is confusing. You say the  laptop has Windows 10 Pro preinstalled. It's already there. Also, formatting the disk will only erase what's on it.

Comment: Sorry my bad... It is Windows  10 home

Comment: You should be able to easily do that by following these [instructions](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-easily-upgrade-windows-10-home-windows-10-pro)

Comment: I had a look at this link before posting here. The link talks about updating through Windows update... I have a MSDN retail disk...

Comment: The only way to go from Windows 10 to Windows 10 Professional, without having to format your machine, is to use the  Windows 10 Pro Pack.  If you have a Windows 10 Professional license, just perform the upgrade, as depicted [here](http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/uploads/2015/07/changeprodkey.jpg)

Comment: Sure... I'll try that...

Comment: Hi Kaveesh. No problem. I rescinded my close vote. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I don't know why so many people are commenting that you need the "Pro Pack" purchase; that's completely false. You only need a valid (i.e. not yet used) Win 10 Pro license key. The "Pro Pack" purchase is one way to get such a license key, but it's definitely not the *only* way.

While the links provided all point you in more-or-less the right direction, the best set of instructions I've seen is here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-win_upgrade/how-to-perform-an-easy-upgrade-in-windows-10/cc29bd00-1f1f-47e7-8397-ec30e8adbf8a

Skip the short paragraph that starts "**Purchase Windows 10 Pro Pack upgrade from within Windows 10 Home** and instead start with "**Once you have your Windows 10 key ready....**" immediately beneath it (where the screenshots start).

Comment: Yeah RamHound mentioned this... I will try that